# Splitting a string and keeping the delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

Hi guys I have been trying to see if I can split a string a keep the separators as separate elements in the new string array but have found it difficult. This is exactly what I want to achieve....

If I have string `"8*(4+x)+7"`...

I will split with operators and parenthesis and get something like... `"8","*", "(", "4", "+", "x", ")", "+", "7"`....

I have read many answers here about how to do that with Regex.Split and tried many of them but I don't get what I want.

Comment: You don't need to Split the string. Tell if split is not necessarily to be used?

Comment: I do not notice any splitting. It looks like you just want a character array. You can already enumerate a string with `foreach` or call `MyString.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: @Silvermind - He probably want numbers like "10" to remain as a separate string.

Comment: Hassan, It is necessary because the number could be more than 1 digit and also the variable x could contain more than 1 character, so a string array is needed hence the splitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't Split - Match!

```
var equation = "8 * (42+xyz)+7";
var tokens = Regex.Matches(equation, @"\d+|\w+|\S")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value);
```

This [regular expression pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) matches one of

- A series of digits - e.g. `8`, `42`
- A series of word characters - e.g. `xyz` (it will also match `x_2`)
- A single non-whitespace character - e.g. `*`, `(`

The match is performed multiple times (via [Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and each successfully matched value is selected into the resulting `IEnumerable<string>`.

Unlike with a traditional Split, there is no explicit separator with this approach as the separation is determined simply by where each match stops and the next match begins. This is also why the white-space is skipped: it just isn't matched.

To specify the operators or "separators" explicitly, simply replace `\S` (which matches any non-whitespace character) with a pattern like `[+*()]` (which only matches the specified operators and parenthesis).

While this is a very simple tokenizer that accomplishes the requested task, it is often useful to add additional [lexeme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) information at this stage.

Comment: What will it return? a string array? and where to list the separators

Comment: It will return an `IEnumerable<string>`. There are no separators with this approach - merely how much each match will "eat" as the separation is determined by where each match *stops*.

Comment: thanks but this will also not work if i have an Identifier X2, it will separate the x and the 2

Comment: @user3442256 This will tokenize `1+x2` as `1,+,x2` - it doesn't separate numbers *following* letters. And if it doesn't work, please provide the input used so I can see as well! If you need want to match `2x` as an identifier (which I would recommend *not* doing), then simply use `\w+|\S` as the regular expression (read: matches a series of word characters, or a single non-space character).

Comment: @user3442256 While I've purposefully kept the regular expression rules simple and left it as a single method approach a "proper" tokenizer would have *specific* rules for each type of token (e.g. number, variable, operator), likely use a longest-match precedence, and report non-matchable data.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "8400*(413+x)+700";
List<string> lstArray = new List<string>();

 for(int i=0; i<str.Length; i++)
 {
      if (Char.IsNumber(str[i]))
      {
           string sNum = str[i].ToString();

           if ((i + 1) < str.Length)
           {
                 for (int k = i+1; k < str.Length; k++)
                 {
                     if (Char.IsNumber(str[k]) == true)
                     {
                         sNum += str[k].ToString();
                         i = i + 1;
                     }
                     else
                        break;
                  }
           }
           lstArray.Add(sNum);
       }
       else if (Char.IsSymbol(str[i]))
       {
            lstArray.Add(str[i].ToString());                                  
       }
       else if (Char.IsLetter(str[i]))
       {
           string sLetter = str[i].ToString();

           if ((i + 1) < str.Length)
           {
              for (int k = i + 1; k < str.Length; k++)
              {
                  if (Char.IsLetter(str[k]) == true)
                  {
                      sLetter += str[k].ToString();
                      i = i + 1;
                  }
                  else
                      break;
              }
          }
          lstArray.Add(sLetter);
      }
      else if (Char.IsPunctuation(str[i]))
      {                   
          lstArray.Add(str[i].ToString());
      }
  }
```

Above code should work. 
Printing the list having comma between the values should be like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lstArray.ToArray()));
```

Here is example input and output:

```
 //Input     
 8400*(413+xyz)+700

 //Output
 8400,*,(,413,+,xyz,),+,700
```

or you could loop through `lstArray`:

```
 foreach(string s in lstArray)
     Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: @user2864740 can explain how?

Comment: Like i said the numbers could include numbers like 10 so this will not work

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable<string>> split = null;
split = (ss, cs) =>
{
    if (!cs.Any())
    {
        return ss;
    }
    else
    {
        var c = cs.First();
        return ss.SelectMany(s0 =>
        {
            var parts = s0.Split(c);
            return split(
                parts
                    .Take(1)
                    .Concat(
                        parts
                            .Skip(1)
                            .SelectMany(p => new [] { new string(c, 1), p })),
                cs.Skip(1));
        })
        .Where(s0 => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s0));
    }
};
```

(Please note that the double assignment of `split` is necessary as this is a recursive function.)

So, if I start with this:

```
var s = "80*(45+xy)+27";
var separators = "*+-/()";
```

I can do this:

```
var result = split(new [] { s }, separators);
```

And I end up with this:

[image: result]

Comment: Please I'm really new to programming so I'm sorry if some of my questions sound stupid....what is CS and SS?

Comment: @user3442256 - They are the arguments of the anonymous method `split`. It would be the same as if I declared a new method with the signature `IEnumerable<string> split(IEnumerable<string> ss, IEnumerable<char> cs)`.